# Not able to view a file using crontab

Tags: 12.04, cron

```
cat filename.txt
```

displays the contents of the text file in the same terminal the command is executed.

But
In Crontab when I type

```
* 14 24 3 1 cat filename.txt
```

nothing gets displayed at the time specified.

Comment: Where do you expect this to be displayed?

Comment: in the terminal

Comment: @aash please [edit] your question any persons can understand it the first time he reads it. in which or whom terminal ? Do you know you can get dozens of terminal open at the same time ?

Comment: ok, when we write cat filename, the contents are displayed in the same terminal. that is exactly what I need.

Comment: @aash **Please [edit] your question to add informations, without this someone reading your question and not the comments will not be able to understand your problem**

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send `cat filename.txt`
```

To display a message on screen. `crontab` itself doesn't know where to print that file. It has no terminal attached. Also it doesn't know to which `DISPLAY` to put info, so I put it manually.

Comment: sorry for the short downvote, miscicked

Comment: I even didn't notice it. Thanks for upvote :)

Comment: should I add notify-send in crontab?

Comment: @aash, yes, put the full command in `crontab`.

Comment: still I don't get anything. Nothing happens at that time

Comment: hmm… I was facing with the same problem. Just add `DISPLAY=:0` before the command

Comment: do you mean like this :- display=:0 notify-send 'cat filename.txt'